# d3 line chart v3 upgrade to v4 - transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have testing this example which is using d3 v3 version:

http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/raw/4063326/

But I'm using the v4 version, I already change:

```
d3.scale.linear() -> d3.scaleLinear()

d3.svg.line() -> d3.line()

remove .interpolate("cardinal")
```

But still facing some error with `transation`

```
  // v3 version 
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .ease("linear")
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

please help me to convert it to v4 version.

Thanks.

Comment: [*The transition.ease method now always takes an easing function, not a string.*](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#transitions-d3-transition): https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#easings-d3-ease

Comment: I change the transition to v4 version, but this example is not working :(